# copy files from a folder to another every 1 hour

Tags: python

As the title says,
I would like to make a script copying files or folders from a specific location to another; every 1 hour.
Any ideas?

I have found a might-be helpfule script using Python but only for copying files; not for setting time.

Thanks in advance

```
def copy(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.py', '*.sh', 'specificfile.file'))
    except OSError as e:
        # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dest)
        else:
            print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
```

Comment: You are missing the javascript tag..

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Do you even understand what "your" code is doing?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I am trying to write/find a code/software/script that copies all files/folders from C:\Users\user\Desktop\pytest\src to C:\Users\user\Desktop\pytest\dest

Answer (score 1):

You could hook your python script up to a scheduled task, then Windows will handle the timing for you.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: and cron is your friend under linux